# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid block name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I am trying to connect Netbeans 13 with Microsoft SQL Server Studio and getting this error. Can anyone help me solving this problem.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class MyJdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     try{   
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName:myFirstDatabase;user=sa;password=Faizan@123";
        Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
     }
     catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println(e.toString());
     }   
    } 
}
```

**Error:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid block name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.base/java.lang.Character$UnicodeBlock.forName(Character.java:4256)
at myjdbc.MyJdbc.main(MyJdbc.java:11)

Comment: The exception suggests your code has `Character.UnicodeBlock.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` instead of `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`. Have you tried recompiling?

Comment: Also, note that you don't need to use `Class.forName` to load the class anyway.  Assuming that the driver JAR is on the classpath, `DriverManager` should find it and load the `SQLServerDriver` class automatically.

Comment: Thanks I removed Class.forname but then again I am getting : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value. any suggestions please?

Comment: Instead of `databaseName:myFirstDatabase;` have you tried `databaseName=myFirstDatabase;` yet?

Comment: Well, tried now and a new error occured: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter. Maybe this is the last. What should I do now?